# How to make multiple form fields under one Semantic UI accordion?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want to hide multiple form fields under one accordion in Semantic UI react, but the example only shows one form field "Maiden Name" under an accordion. No matter what I try, I cannot get a second form field to show under the first one.

Code Sandbox is found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0p0w5?module=/example.js&file=/example.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Accordion, Button, Form, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panels = [
  {
    key: 'details',
    title: 'Optional Details',
    content: {
      as: Form.Input,
      label: 'Maiden Name',
      placeholder: 'Maiden Name',
    },
  },
]

const AccordionExampleForm = () => (
  <Segment>
    <Form>
      <Form.Group widths={2}>
        <Form.Input label='First Name' placeholder='First Name' />
        <Form.Input label='Last Name' placeholder='Last Name' />
      </Form.Group>
      <Accordion as={Form.Field} panels={panels} />

      <Button secondary>Sign Up</Button>
    </Form>
  </Segment>
)

export default AccordionExampleForm
```

Thank you in advance.